# Is ReactJs Compatible with BreezeJS?

Tags: reactjs, breeze

Can we use ReactJS with BreezeJS just like we use AngularJs with BreezeJS for rich data management on the client-side? We are evaluating ReactJS for our enterprise. Thanks